How to determine the law of plotting?
In the book on the calculation of Dobrovolsky's rocket engines, there is a graph according to which Xa counts. But is there a dependency on which this graph was built so that I can write code to accurately determine it.
Pages 46 - 49:
Dobrovolsky's

UPD:
Ra - radius on the nozzle section
Rкр - the radius of the critical section of the nozzle
Xa - the length of the nozzle outlet
